# Vuforia eclipse from scratch

Tags: android, eclipse, vuforia

I have been looking for this for ever on the internet, but I can't seem to find it:

I want to create an augmented reality app for Android using Qualcom Vuforia and Eclipse.

Compiling and installing the Vuforia sample app worked, but I just don't get the logic of all behind it.

Do you know a thinner/ lighter tutorial for starting with Vuforia? (NO UNITY!!)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what exactly you are looking for - a tutorial for starting with it is one thing, and understanding the logic behind it is another thing...
Anyway, you can start here:
[Getting started with Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started).

What exactly it is they are doing would not be revealed, of course, as it is not an open-source library, but you can learn some things from the Articles section. They have explanations on several topics, one of which could also assist you to better understand what's going on there:
[Natural Features and Image Ratings](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Natural-Features-and-Ratings)